# Click on an element highlights other element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there any way to change the attributes of an element when clicking on another element? For example, consider this approach where I have a link like so:

```
<a href="#100">Click me!</a>
```

And then close to it I have this:

```
<span id="100" class="clickTarget">Important text</span>
```

And then on my css file I have this:

```
.clickTarget:target {
    color: #4f8dd5;
}
```

That means whenever the link is clicked, `Important text` changes its color. The problem with this approach is that the page is also scrolled even if only a bit. Is there any other way to do this that doesn't scroll the page?

You can use jQuery if you see fit.

Comment: I know it doesnt answer the question, but you can include the whole jQuery in the same html file.

Comment: you can download jQuery source, store in your local storage and include in your web page.

Comment: Really? Alright, that simplifies things... jQuery is now allowed then.

Comment: `<a href="#100" onclick="return false;">Click me!</a>` solves the scrolling issue, why would you need jQuery for this ?

Comment: @adeneo - return false will also prevent color changes of target element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work with multiple links:

change your css to:

```
.clickTarget.target {
    color: #4f8dd5;
}
```

give your links a common class ie `link`

```
$('a.link').on('click', function() {
   $('.target').removeClass('target');
   var id = $(this).attr('href');
   $(id).addClass('target');
   return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8S5mD/2/

Comment: Your answer seems to me the simplest and cleanest, but I can't get it to work. I added these two lines to the head of my page: `<script src="scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="scripts/links.js"></script>` and the links.js file has the code you wrote. Do I need to do something else? I'm very new to jquery.

Comment: Add code like this in link.js $(document).ready(function(){ that above code});

Comment: The `script` linking `links.js` has to be included after the jQuery one.
my code in links.js should be wrapper around `$(document).ready(function() { //mycode });` alternatively you can put the `script` tags at the bottom of the html page instead of the head. http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

Add an attribute `data-id` (or other names) to your `a` link to specify the id of the associated `span`.

```html
<a href="#100" data-id="100">Click me!</a>
```

And here is javascript:

```js
window.onload = function () {
    var alinks = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i = 0; i < alinks.length; i++) {
        alinks[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
            var id = this.getAttribute('data-id');
            var span = document.getElementById(id);
            span.style.color = '#4f8dd5';
        });
    }
}
```

See example at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ArieShout/cJm8r/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose something like this should work for you:

CSS:

```
   .target{
       color:#4f8dd5;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" data-target="#100">click me<a>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function(e) {
   if($(this).data("target")) {
     e.preventDefault(); //just to avoid # appearing in address after click.
     $(".target").removeClass("target");
     $($(this).data("target")).addClass("target");
   }
})
```

This way ANY (even if it was added after code above is executed) link will run a function and if it has a data-target attribute, it will be used as a jquery selector to find an element which should be highlighted.

**UPD:**

Changed to reflect behavior of target (only one element should be highlighted at once) pointed by  David Fregoli

Comment: this will leave any previously selected element highlighted though

Comment: Oops. Reasonable. I missed that behavior of `:target`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
    $("a").bind('click',function(e){
          if(!$("span.clickTarget").hasClass('changeTextColor')){
             $("span.clickTarget").addClass('changeTextColor');
           }
     });
```

css:

```
    .changeTextColor {
         color: #4f8dd5;
    }
```