# Javascript simple function for selecting element and deselecting all others

Tags: javascript

I have a simple function that is supposed to check if an element has a class. If it doesnt have the class, it should add the class. It should also iterate through all other elements in the series, and deselect them. So only 1 element should be shown at any time.  I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24300118/blurunfocus-an-element-when-other-element-is-clicked), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15702323/click-on-an-element-highlights-other-element), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42327031/checkbox-select-deselect-all-and-perform-function) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33962645/angularjs-how-to-unselect-a-span-when-selecting-another) as well as a bunch of others. I know the function should be simple, but I just cant resolve it.

```
const changeFilter = (itemNumber) => {
// grab element that has been clicked
let selector = document.getElementsByClassName(itemNumber);
// check if element doesnt has the class name that underlines it
if (!selector[0].classList.contains("darken-filter-selector")) {
  // add the class if it doesnt have it
  selector[0].classList.add("darken-filter-selector")
} else {
  // iterate through all the elements, check if it has the class
  // remove it if it doesnt have the class
  for (let i = 0; i < 7 ; i++) {
    if(i !== itemNumber) {
      return selector[i].classList.contains("darken-filter-selector") ? selector[0].classList.remove("darken-filter-selector"):null
    }
  }
}
};
```

And it should *not* look like this (what is currently happening)
[image: gif of incident]

but rather should only allow for one selected element at a time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with this function, as I thought it was the easiest and required the least modification from my original function

```
  const changeFilter = (itemNumber) => {
    // grab element that has been clicked
    let selector = document.getElementsByClassName(itemNumber);
    // check if element doesnt has the class name that underlines it
    if (!selector[0].classList.contains("darken-filter-selector")) {
      // add the class if it doesnt have it
      selector[0].classList.add("darken-filter-selector");
    }
    // iterate through all the elements, check if it has the class
    // remove it if it doesnt have the class
    for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      if (i !== itemNumber) {
        let otherEls = document.getElementsByClassName(i);
        if (otherEls[0].classList.contains("darken-filter-selector")) {
          otherEls[0].classList.remove("darken-filter-selector");
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to store the previous `itemNumber` into global variable like `previousItemNumber`.

- Set the initial value of `previousItemNumber` to `-1` (lower than 0) so that it can be used on `changeFilter` function.
- And on `changeFilter` function, first, you check if `previousItemNumber` is existed or not (in other words, already selected item is existed or not when selecting new item) and if existed, remove the `className` there.
- Add the `className` for the selected item and set the current `itemNumber` to `previousItemNumber`.

```js
let previousItemNumber = -1;

const changeFilter = (itemNumber) => {
  // grab element that has been clicked
  let selector = document.getElementsByClassName(itemNumber);
  
  if (previousItemNumber === itemNumber) {
    return;
  }
  
  // Remove the class from previous selector
  if (previousItemNumber >= 0) {
    selector[previousItemNumber].classList.remove("darken-filter-selector");
  }
  selector[itemNumber].classList.add("darken-filter-selector");
  previousItemNumber = itemNumber;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired using input `type="checkbox"` and a bit of JS:

```js
const EL_checkboxesOne = document.querySelectorAll(".checkboxesOne");

const checkboxesOne = (EL_group) => {
  const inputs = EL_group.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]');
  EL_group.addEventListener("input", (ev) => {
    [...inputs].filter(EL => EL !== ev.target).forEach(EL => EL.checked = false);
  });
};

EL_checkboxesOne.forEach(checkboxesOne);
```

```css
.checkboxesOne {
  display: flex;
  font: bold 16px/1.4 sans-serif;
  color: #666;
}

.checkboxesOne input {
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 1px;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  clip-path: inset(100%);
}

.checkboxesOne span {
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 0 10px;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.checkboxesOne input:checked + span {
  box-shadow: 0 4px green;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkboxesOne">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="all"><span>ALL</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="new"><span>NEW</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="wip"><span>WIP</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="hot"><span>HOT</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="won"><span>WON</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="lost"><span>LOST</span></label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="filter" value="dnc"><span>DNC</span></label>
</div>
```

Comment: I would much rather use the html that i was given instead of changing everything to a checkbox system.

Answer (score 0):

This is my suggestion. It uses *Event Delegation*. Change the style as you like.

```js
options.onclick = function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName != "LI") return;
  var selected = options.querySelector(".active");
  if (selected) {
    selected.removeAttribute("class");
  }
  e.target.setAttribute("class", "active");
  console.log(e.target.dataset.option);
};
```

```css
#options {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#options li {
  margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style: none;
}

#options li.active {
  background-color: green;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="options">
  <li data-option="all">ALL</li>
  <li data-option="new">NEW</li>
  <li data-option="wip">WIP</li>
  <li data-option="hot">HOT</li>
  <li data-option="won">WON</li>
  <li data-option="lost">LOST</li>
  <li data-option="dnc">DNC</li>
</ul>
```

You can also do without using *Data Attribute* (data-option="..."): just use `e.target.innerHTML`.